# How to overcome screen size problems in android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I am beginner to android application development.I would like to make one small kids play android application.i started working on 3.7" android screen.if i tried any other screen my xml or ui design is collapsed.it s getting totally wrong order.how to overcome this problem?
if i want to make application tablets also ie;7".Can i make differnt xml layout for each screen size or any other simple solution?

Comment: Here you will find all you need to know. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your xml?
Three general advices:

1. Do not use hardcoded values to specify coordinates and dimensions.
2. Try using RelativeLayout.
3. Provide different images for different
   resolutions.

Comment: so , i have to create xml file for each screen size small,medium,large like that??

Answer (score 2):

You can design different Layout for different size of screen

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

1. Use "match parent" and "wrap content" for providing width and height of most views.
2. Use dp and sp instead of px for size.

3 use  different size of image for different screen

eg

for ldpi = 36 * 36 px mdpi = 48 * 48 px hdpi = 72 * 72 px xhdpi = 96 * 96 px

4 Use different drawable folder for each orientation.